# Get Wordpress Post ID From Product On WooCommerce Checkout Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom fields such as "cleaning fee" and "security deposit" that I want to add to the item on the checkout page and I figured that this would be pretty straight forward but I don't see any association between the item and the custom post that the item is derived from. I would somehow have to get the post id from the item to be able to use a line like so...

```
<?php $thisItemsSecurityDeposit = get_post_meta($cart_item['the post id'], 'accommodation_security_deposit', true ); echo $thisItemsSecurityDeposit ; ?>
```

...and have the security deposit included right after the item's price.

I was thinking that maybe there was some object or session variable array that held keys that associated the product with the post id that the product came from.

See...
http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/hotels/spanish-modern-retreat/
Then, click "Availability" then click "Book Now" to see the cart in action.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cart_contents` variable of the cart object (`WC()->cart->cart_contents`) includes an array of information for each item in the cart... a `var_dump` of my sample cart contents looks like the following:

```
["cart_contents"]=> array(1) {
    ["7cbbc409ec990f19c78c75bd1e06f215"]=>
        array(5) {
        ["product_id"]=> int(70)
        ["variation_id"]=> string(0) ""
        ["variation"]=> string(0) ""
        ["quantity"]=> int(1)
        ["data"]=> object(WC_Product_Simple)#530 (3) {
            ["id"]=> int(70)
            ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#532 (24) {
                ["ID"]=> int(70)
                ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1"
                ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2013-06-07 11:25:01"
                ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2013-06-07 11:25:01"
                ["post_content"]=> string(278) "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo."
                ["post_title"]=> string(12) "Flying Ninja"
                ["post_excerpt"]=> string(278) "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo."
                ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish"
                ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open"
                ["ping_status"]=> string(6) "closed"
                ["post_password"]=> string(0) ""
                ["post_name"]=> string(12) "flying-ninja"
                ["to_ping"]=> string(0) ""
                ["pinged"]=> string(0) ""
                ["post_modified"]=> string(19) "2014-10-06 16:53:48"
                ["post_modified_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-10-06 16:53:48"
                ["post_content_filtered"]=> string(0) ""
                ["post_parent"]=> int(0)
                ["guid"]=> string(67) "http://demo2.woothemes.com/woocommerce/?post_type=product&amp;p=70"
                ["menu_order"]=> int(0)
                ["post_type"]=> string(7) "product"
                ["post_mime_type"]=> string(0) ""
                ["comment_count"]=> string(1) "4"
                ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw"
            }
            ["product_type"]=>    string(6) "simple"
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, in a `foreach()` loop over the cart contents, the product ID would be grabbed like so:

```
$contents = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
if( $contents ) foreach ( $contents as $cart_item ){
  echo $cart_item['product_id'];
}
```

If you already have the specific `$cart_item` variable (ex: you are in the cart template and already inside Woo's loop) then you'd just access the `product_id` array. `$cart_item['product_id'];` I always find it helpful to use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` to know what variables or array keys are available to me.

As an aside, you might want to take a look at [Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/) which would do exactly what you are describing.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your input Helga but I simply needed the post_id of the post that the woo commerce product was derived from. I was able to run a custom wp query on the post table for the product title which is the same as the post title and I also queried for the post type and post status so that I could obtain the post id. See code below...

Comment: global $wpdb;
         
         //using the product title, find the post id.
          $querystr = "
          SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID 
          FROM $wpdb->posts
          WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_title = '$this_products_title'
          AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
          AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'accommodation'
          AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
          ";

          $pageposts = $wpdb->get_row($querystr, ARRAY_A);
          
          //print_r($pageposts);
          //echo $pageposts[ID];

Comment: That's a little too much code to be legible in the comments. Could you edit your question and properly format the code so I can read it? However, unless you are using the Sequential Order Numbers plugin, the product id IS the post ID. Hence, `$cart_item['product_id'];` IS the post id for that particular item in the cart.

Comment: The above isn't true for woo commerce. It totally assigns its own product id based off of god knows what. I tried to indent the code but since its in a comment box the behavior isn't the same as if this was the main post.

Comment: In any case. I'm beyond that problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can use back-ticks in the comments. And I assure you that product id *is* the same as the post id, except as I mentioned, in the case of Sequential Order Numbers. The cart key is a totally different matter.